# Wordpress CSS breaks in Chrome when served over SSL

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Running into a really strange problem. We just purchased a premium SSL certificate from GoDaddy. The techs at our hosting company installed it, and everything seems to be working fine when I view the webpage in Firefox and/or Internet Explorer:

https://moneythink.org/donate2/

Problem is, when I view the same page in Chrome, it seems like the CSS does not load (it's a Wordpress-based website, by the way). I installed a "Wordpress HTTPS" plugin to fix the "this page is not secure" problems that were popping up, and from what I can tell, there is no mixed content in any of the browsers now -- the CSS just refuses to load when viewed from Chrome.

Any ideas what's going on, and how to fix it?

Comment: What does Chrome do when you try to request the CSS file directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to actually able to fix the problem! Turns out, when I was logged into Wordpress, the browser was unable to serve one of the images associated with the WP admin bar, resulting in a 404 error. For whatever reason, that made the whole site break.

As long as the visitor is not logged in, all works fine (explains why I was getting the results above, as I was logged in when I viewed the site in Chrome, but was logged out when I did so in Firefox and IE).